# Quiero buscar texto dentro de varios archivos con python, desconozco la cantidad de archivos

Tags: python-3.x

espero esten bien.
necesito buscar una cadena de caracteres dentro de varios archivos de texto con python,(desconozco la cantidad de archivos)
una vez encontrada la cadena de caracteres, quiero que me imprima el nombre del archivo donde encontro el texto
Comparto lo que tengo hasta el momento

```
import os
import io

work_dir = "C:/Users/%username%/Desktop"

for index in range(1, 2):
    name = "item{index}.txt".format(index=index)
    path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        content = fd.read()

    print('Escribe texto a buscar dentro de archivos.')
    typedText = input()
    Flag = 0
    for i in content.split('\n'):
        if typedText == i:
            Flag = 1
    if Flag == 1:
        print('Texto encontrado' + nombre_archivo)

    else:
        print('texto no encontrado')
```

Comment: Haz una función que recibe un nombre de archivo y busque en él el texto. Haz un ciclo sobre la lista de archivos, y por cada uno llama a la función anterior.

Comment: Intentaste haciendo lo propuesto por Candid Moe con alguno de los modulos que sirven para listar archivos (pathlib, os o glob)?

Answer (score 0):

Con la palabra reservada "in" puedes hacer busquedas rapidas en cadenas de texto sin ningun esfuerzo.

---

## SOLUCION

```
import os 
import io

work_dir = "C:/Users/%username%/Desktop"

for index in range(1, 2):
    name = "item{index}.txt".format(index=index)
    path = os.path.join(work_dir, name)
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
        content = fd.read()

    print('Escribe texto a buscar dentro de archivos.')
    typedText = input()

    
    for linea in content.split('\n'):
        if typedText in linea:
           print('Texto encontrado en:' + name )
           break
        print('texto no encontrado')
```